# How to download a html page via asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how can i download a web page from my web app, then reading "title" and "description" metatag ?
Like a web crawler, but in Asp.net and called by ..an asp.net web page ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a *screen scrape* of an external URL in .NET using the [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient), which you'll find in the `System.Net` namespace. Use the `DownloadData` method to download the content from a specified URL. The downloaded data comes down as a byte array, but you can convert this to a string.

The following snippet shows how to use `WebClient` to grab the HTML from my blog's homepage, http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/default.aspx:

```
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

// Download the markup from 
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData("http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/default.aspx");

// Convert the downloaded data into a string
string markup = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
```

Once you have the markup you can use regular expressions or string searching methods to pick out the markup of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and its `HTMLWeb` class.